# Sending New order email programatically to custom email adress

Tags: magento2, order-email

I'm creating a module that checks if the order was made by a certain group, in this case wholesale groups, and if yes send the copy to new order email to a different email address.
It's okay if it still sends to the main address but I can't add another one in the admin area because only the wholesale ones matter.
I already created a module with a sales_order_save_after event and Observer, but I don't know how to get the new order email of that order and send it again to the custom email.

Thanks!
Best regards,
Rui Silva

Comment: Hope this can help: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-send-order-email-custom-email-address-magento-2.html

Comment: Hey @AmitSaini, I checked wouldn't this $order->setCustomerEmail($email); change the customer email set in the order? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        StateInterface $state
    )
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $state;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        // this is an example and you can change template id,fromEmail,toEmail,etc as per your need.
        $templateId = 'my_custom_email_template'; // template id
        $fromEmail = 'owner@domain.com';  // sender Email id
        $fromName = 'Admin';             // sender Name
        $toEmail = 'customer@email.com'; // receiver email id

        try {
            // template variables pass here
            $templateVars = [
                'msg' => 'test',
                'msg1' => 'test1'
            ];

            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $templateOptions = [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($toEmail)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, with that option how do I get the New order email template, if I just insert the ID on $templateId it will work or the base vars would not work and would need to create ones just for this one? Thanks!